# How much Fury do you gain when you are attacked?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

The Fury-generating skills are very clear regarding how much Fury they give. But I know the Barbarian also gains Fury when attacked. **How much Fury does the Barbarian gain when attacked, and does it depend on the damage inflicted?**

- If it does depend on the damage inflicted, how does damage reduction come into play?
- If an attack was dodged, is Fury still generated?

Comment: it interests me very much

Answer (score 1):

**We don't currently know** Analysis could be done, but due to the nature of Diablo 3 and not having any sort of a combat log, it would be quite tricky.

**My best guess is they use the same/similar mechanics to WoWs rage**
The way this works in WoW is The amount varies based on the character's health. Attacks that are blocked, parried, or absorbed generate rage.

**WoW still does not have exact mechanics available for rage** This leads me to believe that if Blizzard wants to keep these details secret they can and will. Most likely they will also tweak these values as they see fit. This is another advantage to having everything on the server side, Blizzard can keep the game in balance as they see fit.

Comment: Considering how crucial fury is to the class, and how often the rage formulas have been changed, I agree Blizzard will tweak continuously. But we should be able to discover the formulas. It's harder without a combat log, but don't doubt the powers of science, and stubborn gamers!

Answer (score 1):

I get four Fury per attack when not critting no matter what I attack with a normal attack.

As for Fury gained when being attacked I know that I can gain an easy 20 Fury over 4-6 seconds of being attacked by one or two mobs in Act 3 Inferno. I just tried it in Act 1 on Normal with my lvl 60 and I did not gain any Fury when I was hit.

Answer (score 0):

I know if an attack is dodged then no fury is generated , as for how much fury you get when you get hit , its seems to be a low percentage , not sure though

Comment: can you confirm the amount?